# Bootstrap Selectpicker not refreshing

Tags: ajax, promise, jquery-deferred, bootstrap-selectpicker

When a user clicks the edit icon the contents of a selectpicker are updated then refreshed. Then the selectpicker's value is updated, then refreshed again, but for some reason it is not updating with the selected value.

Everything works fine when I manually enter in the the same code in the console.

```
$('#IncWidgetId').val(864)// the value used when breaking in console
$('#IncWidgetId').selectpicker('refresh')
```

I have ensured that the selectpicker is updated with the new option values along with confirming the deferred is firing in the proper order. 
As a double check, I also have separated the `.selectpicker('refresh')` to make sure it didn't try to fire before the option was selected due to async, but it is still not updating the selectpicker with the selected value.

```js
$(document).on('click', '[id^=EditWidgetId-]', function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
  var mfg = $(this).data('mfg');
  var widgetid = $(this).data('widgetid ');
  var mfgSelect = $('input[name=mfg][value="' + mfg + '"]');
  mfgSelect.prop('checked', true);

  $.when(LoadWidgets(mfg)).then(function () {
      console.log('then function');
      $('#IncWidgetId').val(widgetid );
  }).done(function () {
      console.log('done function');
      $('#IncWidgetId').selectpicker('refresh');
  });

  $('#modalWidgetNew').modal('show');
});

function LoadWidgets(mfg) {
  var r = $.Deferred();
  console.log('before ajax');

  r.resolve($.ajax({
      url: '/Widgets/FilterWidgetsDropdown',
      type: 'GET',
      cache: false,
      data: { mfg: mfg },
      success: function (partial) {
          $('#IncWidgetDDArea').html(partial);
          $('#IncWidgetId').selectpicker('refresh')
      },
      error: function (x, e) {
          if (x.status == 0) {
              alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
          } else if (x.status == 404) {
              alert('Requested URL not found.');
          } else if (x.status == 500) {
              alert('Internel Server Error.');
          } else if (e == 'parsererror') {
              alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
          } else if (e == 'timeout') {
              alert('Request Time out.');
          } else {
              alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
          }
      }
  })).done(function () {
      console.log('after ajax');
      return r.promise();
  });
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

There was such an issue in old versions of this plugin.
 
Try to destroy it and initialize again. Something like this:

```
$('#IncWidgetId').selectpicker('destroy');
$('#IncWidgetId').selectpicker();
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and good to know for the future. I tried implementing this a few different ways, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: It looks like your console.log('after ajax') runs before the ajax request is really done. Try to refresh selectpicker by using setTimeout() function with a 3-4 secs delay.

Comment: And you missed the $ symbol in this line: `('#modalWidgetNew').modal('show');`
It couldn't screw up selectpicker plugin work but it's better to fix it anyway.

Comment: Sorry for bothering again, but I used this plugin many times and it always worked well. When I ran into issues I just carefully logged every step and state of the objects. And after a thorough analysis I always found the root of the problem. I'm sure that your issue can be resolved the same way.